# Deleting a rows with invalid date in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df:
date       value
20171231   500
20161231   321.25
20111512   234
20151215   900.7
19900101   6252.1
19791131   123
...
```

where date column is an integer and in the format YYYYMMDD. Before converting into **pd.to_datetime** I want to filter this column with valid dates between 1980 to present day.

What would be an efficient way to perform this operation? using regexp or any other pandas method available?

Comment: Why not convert to date then filter?

Comment: then I'm getting an error while converting itself.

Comment: Then I would say that is your problem - would rephrase the question to be that and post the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert to datetime with parameter `errors='coerce'` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) or double conditions:

```
today = pd.datetime.today()
print (today)
2018-01-09 10:51:42.701585

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')

df = df[df['date'].between('1980-01-01', today)]
```

```
df = df[(df['date'] > '1980-01-01') & (df['date'] < today)]
```

```
df = df.query("'1980-01-01' < date < @today")
```

---

```
print (df)
        date    value
0 2017-12-31   500.00
1 2016-12-31   321.25
3 2015-12-15   900.70
4 1990-01-01  6252.10
```

Comment: The thing is date column contains bad data like month value can be 15 or February can have 30 days(20170230). That's why I want to filter out the date column before converting it into date.